# How to solve this ODE (answer is given as implicit equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is from Boas 9.2, Problem 1

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\sqrt x y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\right) = 0 $$

And therefore

$$ \frac{\sqrt x y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} = k, ~~ k\textrm{ constant} $$

But then what? The answer is given implicitly as

$$(y-b)^2=4a^2(x-a^2), ~~ a,b\textrm{ constants} $$

She has several similar problems, (as part of solving Euler-Lagrange equations), but doesn't give details on how to solve this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $y'$ has the same sign as $k$, as the square root as function always takes non-negative values.

Then square and isolate $y'$,
$$
xy'^2=k^2(1+y'^2)
\\
(x-k^2)y'^2=k^2
\\
y'=\frac{k}{\sqrt{x-k^2}}
$$
This also contains the implicit condition $x>k^2$.
Now integrate
$$
y=m+2k\sqrt{x-k^2}.
$$
This can now be transformed into something similar but not equal to the claimed form.

Comment: Thanks. I had a typo on the claimed form, now corrected and consistent with yours!